# How to Add Existing File to file_managed. File is Blank

Tags: 7, files

I have manually added some files to the Private Files directory on my Drupal 7 site and wish to add them to the `file_managed` table in the database.

**This is what I have attempted:**

1. Load the existing file with the [file_get_contents($PATH_TO_FILE)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.
2. Used the [file_save_data($loaded_file, $destination, FILE_EXISTING_REPLACE)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7.x) function save the file and add it to the Database.

**The Result:**

1. *The expected file is in the File System but is 0 bytes and blank*
2. File is added to Database

The main issue is that the existing file isn't getting uploaded properly and is being displayed blank. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your $loaded_file is a file object [enter link description here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34244/creating-a-file-object-from-a-file-already-in-public-drupal-7) not just a file content.

Comment: That did it for me! I was attempting to pass a path to the file. As you suggested, creating a new file object and filling it with relevant info and then saving it that way did it for me. Thank you!